# Output variables of Lambda function as Cloudformation parameters in Codepipeline

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-cloudformation, aws-codepipeline

I have a Codepipeline, and I am trying to pass the output variables of a Lambda function as a parameter of the next stage, a Cloudformation action, in this pipeline. Does anyone know if it can be done?

Comment: The lambda function is called as an action in your pipeline?

Comment: @TimBassett Yes, in the pipeline, my lambda will calculate a value to be inserted as a parameter of the Cloudformation template in the next stage. Could you help?

Answer (score 0):

I found a way. I used a Lambda function to create my Cloudformation stack. The User parameters of this Lambda are the output variables of the previous Lambda, and can be inserted as parameters to the Cloudformation stack.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

You can use the "Invoke Lambda" action within a CodePipeline, include a "Namespace" as part of that action, and then retrieve results from the Lambda's execution in later actions (a "CloudFormation Deploy" type, or other types as well).

Your "Invoke Lambda" action will look something like:

```
- Name: increment-version-number
  RunOrder: 1
  ActionTypeId:
    Category: Invoke
    Owner: AWS
    Version: 1
    Provider: Lambda
   Configuration:
     FunctionName: my-pipeline-executed-function
   Namespace: MyResults
```

CodePipeline will invoke your Lambda, and will pass an input message that contains the data you need to communicate results back to CodePipeline when your Lambda finishes.
Your can see a javascript example of such a Lambda in the official AWS documentation at: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codepipeline/latest/userguide/actions-invoke-lambda-function.html
You can implement your Lambda in any language.  The key pieces of the Lambda are:

1. parse the incoming message packet to find the identifiers you need to pass back to CodePipeline to signal your Lambda has completed.
2. execute the logic needed for your use case
3. invoke an api call back to CodePipeline to signal success (or failure) - that is either:
   putJobSuccessResult (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codepipeline/latest/APIReference/API_PutJobSuccessResult.html)
   or putJobFailureResult (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codepipeline/latest/APIReference/API_PutJobFailureResult.html)
   If you have been successful, then you'll notice part of the api call payload is `outputVariables`.  This is where you can return the values you want to use later in the execution of your CodePipeline.

Here's a psudocode-ish Java example:

```
    public final void handleRequest(InputStream inputStream, OutputStream outputStream, Context context)
    {
        try {
            Object inputJson = jsonProvider.parse(inputStream, StandardCharsets.UTF_8.name());

            final String jobId = JsonPath.read(inputJson, "$.['CodePipeline.job'].id");
            logger.info("jobId={}", jobId);

            try {

                final GetJobDetailsResponse jobDetailsResponse = codePipelineClient.getJobDetails(GetJobDetailsRequest.builder()
                        .jobId(jobId)
                        .build());
                final JobDetails jobDetails = jobDetailsResponse.jobDetails();
                final String pipelineName = jobDetails.data().pipelineContext().pipelineName();
                logger.info("pipelineName={}", pipelineName);

                final Map<String, String> outputVariables = new HashMap<>();

                // do your interesting stuff here, populate the outputVariables map as required

                final GetPipelineStateResponse pipelineStateResponse = codePipelineClient.getPipelineState(GetPipelineStateRequest.builder()
                        .name(pipelineName)
                        .build());

                logger.info("marking job {} completed", jobId);
                codePipelineClient.putJobSuccessResult(
                        PutJobSuccessResultRequest.builder()
                                .jobId(jobId)
                                .outputVariables(outputVariables)
                                .build());

            } catch (Exception e) {
                logger.error("marking job {} failed", jobId);
                codePipelineClient.putJobFailureResult(PutJobFailureResultRequest.builder()
                        .jobId(jobId)
                        .failureDetails(FailureDetails.builder()
                                .type(FailureType.JOB_FAILED)
                                .message(e.getMessage())
                                .build())
                        .build());
                throw e;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            logger.error(context.getAwsRequestId(), e);
        }
}
```

You can finally get around to using the piece(s) of data from your Lambda later in your pipeline!

Use the "hash" notation to retrieve values from your "Namespace", e.g. `#{MyResults.myVariableName}`.

With Cloudformation actions you have the choice of using `TemplateConfiguration` and/or `ParameterOverrides` to pass Cloudformation parameters.  You'll need `ParameterOverrides` for Lambda extracted values (you can mix and match where values come from for parameters, i.e. have some from the `TemplateConfiguration` and others from `ParameterOverrides`), and it might look something like:

```
 - Name: my-deployment
   ActionTypeId:
     Category: Deploy
     Owner: AWS
     Version: 1
     Provider: CloudFormation
   Configuration:
     ActionMode: CREATE_UPDATE
     StackName: my-stack-name
     TemplatePath: MyArtifacts::packaged-infrastructure.cfn.yaml
     TemplateConfiguration: MyArtifacts::pipeline/my-parameters.json
     ParameterOverrides: !Sub >
       {
         "MyParameterFromLambda": "#{MyResults.myVariableName}"
       }
```